# Asp.Net mvc - pass last created id from action to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables. Student and Grade. Grade has a foreign key StudentId, so I know which student got that Grade.

I have an action AddStudent and view has a form, where I insert student data data into database. AddStudent action returns PartialView. In that PartialView I have new form for Grades.

I need to somehow get StudentId(which I should somehow get after I insert data in AddStudent action). How can you pass StudentId from AddStudent action to Grades partial view? Because I need to insert "Grades" with StudentId so I know to which student Grades are intended.

Actions:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult CreateStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView(MVC.Student.Views._AddGrades); // do I have to pass student.Id here to partialView somehow?
        }

        return View(student);
    }
```

Grade action:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult CreateGrade(Grade grade, int studentId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            grade.studentId = studentId; // how to get this from previous action to my partial view?
            db.Grades.Add(grade);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView(MVC.Grades.Views._UpdateTableOfGrades);
        }

        return View(grade);
    }
```

I would really be thankful for some example.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `model` of the `_AddGrades` partial view?

Comment: Model is just `Grade`.

Comment: What does the `Grade` model looks like?

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to skin this cat, but I think `TempData` is what you are after. So, in your first controller you would have this:

```
 TempData["StudentId"] = studentId;
```

`TempData` will last until the end of the next request. If you need it to persist longer, use `ViewData`.

```
 ViewData["StudentId"] = studentId;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Id` property will be filled after you call `db.SaveChanges()`:

```
int studentId = student.Id;
```

You can pass this value to the partial view.

Comment: yes but how? example? and how to use it inside next partialView?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a Get CreateGrade action on your controller and return a RedirectToAction like this :

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Student.CreateGrade)
```

You also need to create a Model for the creation that will contain the StudentId property.

If you use T4MVC you can do this :

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Student.CreateGrade).AddRouteValue("studentid", student.Id);
```

Comment: I dont want to redirect to action, because I use ajax to show partialView after I fill one form and click "Create", partial view shows below and I need studentId for that partialView.

Comment: Then you need to create a new Model (CreateGradeModel) that will contain your Grade info and the StudentId